# More efficient way to perform semi-rowwise operation in python that filters for criteria

Tags: python, list, loops, apply

I have a dataset like below with over a million records. JobNumber can be repeated many times and AccountingCode can have many unique or repeated entries for each JobNumber. I am attempting to get the number of times each AccountingCode appears within a window of 12  to 16 days prior to the end of AccountingCode '022200'.

I have tried various iterations of my code but they are all far too inefficient and take too long to run. Below is an example of my script (windowsJobs is a unique list of all JobNumbers that contain AccountingCode '022200'):

```
def process_costcodes(job):
windowDate = jobTask.loc[(jobTask['JobNumber'] == job)&(jobTask['AccountingCode'] == '022200'), 'ActualStartDate'].values[0]
lowerBound = windowDate - pd.to_timedelta(16, unit='d')
upperBound = windowDate - pd.to_timedelta(12, unit='d')
result = jobTask.loc[(jobTask['JobNumber'] == job)&(jobTask['ActualEndDate'] <= upperBound)&(jobTask['ActualEndDate'] >= lowerBound), 'AccountingCode']
return result

costcode_list = [process_costcodes(job) for job in windowsJobs]
```

Please share any suggestions on how I can improve my code here. I have tried looking at using .apply() but am now sure how it could be implemented here. Any advice or solutions would be appreciated.

| JobNumber | AccountingCode | ActualStartDate | ActualEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 735069 | 032300 | 2022-04-12 | 2022-04-17 10:59:23.803 |
| 735069 | 032300 | 2022-04-13 | 2022-04-18 10:59:23.803 |
| 102252 | 030120 | 2022-04-14 | 2022-04-18 09:57:01.053 |
| 102252 | 030110 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-03 15:40:43.737 |
| 102252 | 035300 | 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-18 10:55:25.753 |
| 102252 | 022700 | 2022-04-19 | 2022-04-19 11:29:18.457 |

Answer (score 1):

Tried converting to numpy array

```
jobbnp = jobTask.to_numpy()

cond1 = jobbnp[np.where((jobTask['JobNumber'] == 102252)&(jobTask['AccountingCode'] == '022700'))]

windowDate = cond1[:,2][0] #2 --> column 'ActualStartDate'

lowerBound = windowDate - pd.to_timedelta(16, unit='d')
upperBound = windowDate - pd.to_timedelta(12, unit='d')

cond2 = jobbnp[np.where((jobTask['JobNumber'] == 102252)&(jobTask['ActualEndDate'] <= upperBound)&(jobTask['ActualEndDate'] >= lowerBound))]
result = cond2[:,1] #1 --> column 'AccountingCode'

print(result)
```

Comment: When I implement this method it doesn't appear to reduce the runtime much if at all. That being said I still learned from it so I appreciate the response.